# How To Set Default Value In NopDropDownList...?

Tags: drop-down-menu, default, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.80

I Have One Field Store And In This Field Three Value

- 1=All
  (This Value Is NopCOmmerce Default Value)
- 2=Store1
- 3=Store2

And I Want To Set Value 1 Or 2

My View Page For Store

```
 <div class="col-md-7">
   <div class="form-group" @(Model.AvailableStores.SelectionIsNotPossible() ? Html.Raw("style=\"display:none\"") : null)>
 <div class="col-md-4">
  @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.StoreId)
   </div>
 <div class="col-md-8">
  @Html.NopDropDownList("StoreId", Model.AvailableStores )
  </div>
  </div>
```

How To Set Value 1 In This View Page...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this;

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
  @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.StoreId)
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-8">
    @Html.NopDropDownListFor(model => model.StoreId, Model.AvailableStores)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StoreId)
 </div>
```